# Get object schema name from SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server named **DFDataBindingTableDefinition**; it stores the database table names. Almost all the tables are under the `dbo` schema, but some of them are under the `cus` schema.
And table names are also the same under the different schema names.
Following is an example of how table names are stored in the table.

**IncidentNote**

**cus.IncidentNote**

I would like to extract the table information along with the underlying schema, so I am using the following query,

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(DFDataBinding.TableName), DB_ID()) AS "Schema",
    DFDataBinding.TableName AS "Name"
    FROM sysobjects Objects
INNER JOIN sys.tables Tables on Tables.object_id = Objects.id
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties TableProperties on TableProperties.major_id = Objects.id
                                        and TableProperties.name = 'MS_Description'
                                        and TableProperties.minor_id = 0
INNER JOIN dbo.DFDataBindingTableDefinition DFDataBinding ON DFDataBinding.DBTableName = Objects.name
```

But it gives me result as

```
Schema Name
dbo    IncidentNote
dbo    IncidentNote
```

I would like it to return `cus` as the schema for one of the results. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Why not `JOIN` to `sys.schemas`? Also why are you use `dbo.sysobjects` (which is for compatibility with SQL Server **2000** databases) rather than `sys.objects`

Comment: This doesn’t repro.  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(‘cus.IncidentNote’)) = ‘cus’.

Answer (score 1):

Tables *cus.IndicentNote* and *dbo.IncidentNote* are diferent objects and have diferent objectids.
If you don't pass the schema part to OBJECT_ID() it will asume the default schema which is **dbo**.

In your query, every row with the value *IncidentNote* in column DFDataBinding.TableName will execute like this: OBJECT_ID('IncidentNote') which translates to OBJECT_ID('**dbo**.IncidentNote'). That will give the same objectid

You can get the schema name by joining the sys.schemas with sys.tables.

```
SELECT 
    schemas.name AS "Schema",
    DFDataBinding.TableName AS "Name"
    FROM sysobjects Objects
INNER JOIN sys.tables Tables on Tables.object_id = Objects.id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas Schemas ON Schemas.schema_id = Tables.schema_id
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties TableProperties on TableProperties.major_id = Objects.id
                                        and TableProperties.name = 'MS_Description'
                                        and TableProperties.minor_id = 0
INNER JOIN dbo.DFDataBindingTableDefinition DFDataBinding ON DFDataBinding.DBTableName = Objects.name
```

Alternatively you can have the same effect with this syntax.

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [Schema],
       t.TABLE_NAME AS [Name]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM DFDataBinding.DBTableName AS DFDataBinding
    WHERE DFDataBinding.DBTableName = t.TABLE_NAME
);
```